# How to get the name of the directories removing the path?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using `for loop` such as

```
for j in ls ${folder}/*
```

to get all subfolders inside my directory (`$folder`).

But I want only the names of the sub-directories and want to remove directory structure. I use `xargs` `basenme` when working with files, but thats not working with directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of all folders in (exactly one level of sub-directories):

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```

You can pipe the result into `sed` command which will leave only the directory name (without the prefix)

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | sed -z 's!.*/!!' |tr '\0' '\n'
```

Example:

```
$ find /var -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1  -type d 
/var/metrics
/var/lib
/var/local
/var/cache
/var/spool
/var/crash
/var/backups
/var/mail
/var/snap
/var/opt
/var/log
/var/tmp

$ find /var -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | sed -z 's!.*/!!' |tr '\0' '\n'
metrics
lib
local
cache
spool
crash
backups
mail
snap
opt
log
tmp
```

Using `for` loop:

```
$ for i in $(find /var -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | sed -z 's!.*/!!' |tr '\0' '\n'); do echo $i; done
metrics
lib
local
cache
spool
crash
backups
mail
snap
opt
log
tmp
```

for loop re-arranged:

```
$ for i in $(find /var -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | sed -z 's!.*/!!' |tr '\0' '\n'); 
    do 
    echo $i
  done
```

Comment: With GNU `find` (which is what Ubuntu uses) you don't need to use external processing to get the basename - you can use `-printf '%f\0'` (or `-printf '%P\0'` to remove just the starting point). Also despite your efforts with `\0`, looping over a command substitution like `for j in $(find ...)` will break if any of the results contain whitespace - better to use a null-delimited `while` loop

Comment: @steeldriver - thanks for your comment! later I'll try to update my answer with the info you add. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`$folder/*/` matches every subdirectory of `$folder`. Use [`bash` Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to cut out the directory name:

```bsh
for j in $folder/*/; do
  j=${j%/}
  j=${j##*/}
  …
done
```

This simply redefines `j` cutting first the last slash and then everything until the last slash in the string, effectively leaving only the subdirectory name.

Answer (score 1):

Better to using `find` command instead of for-loop.

```
find "$folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir printf '%s\n' '{}' +
```

Here we used `-execdir` which that's changing the directory path where a `-d`irectory found, so the `{}` will containing only the last element when printing which is a directory-name.

---

Or with GNU `find` that supports `-printf` option to formatting.

```
find "$folder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

That `-f` is returning only the last element with any leading directories removed.

---

**Note**: this is limited to list sub-directories only in `$folder` specified; you can adjust/remove the `-maxlength` with your requirements.